# My HTML page is showing API data BEFORE user input... don't know where it's from

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a form the user has to complete (variable city) for the Python request to execute. However. when I get the the html (before I input the city) it already shows data.

Here is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/weather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def weather():

    API_KEY = "xxxxx"
    BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    city = None
    temperature = None
    weather = None
    clothing = None

    if request.method =='POST':
        city = request.form.get("city")

    request_url = f"{BASE_URL}?lang=fr&appid={API_KEY}&q={city}"
    response = requests.get(request_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        weather = data["weather"][0]["description"]
        temperature = round(data["main"]["temp"] - 273.15, 2)

#determine which clothing to wear
        clothing = "Choice"
        if temperature >17.00:
            clothing = "t-shirt"
        elif temperature <= 17.00:
            clothing = "Cotton ouaté ou une petite veste"
        elif temperature <=5.00:
            clothing = "Un bon manteau chaud!"
        return render_template("weather.html", weather=weather, temperature=temperature, clothing=clothing, city=city)

    else:
        return ("Problem with your request")
```

I tried setting the city, temperature, weather variables to None. It didn't do anything. I put IF clauses in my html (jinja) to no avail.

Comment: Look at your code: the only difference between a POST and a GET is one line.

Comment: Before, `if request.method =='POST':` add `if request.method =='GET':` and return your form html template.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to replace your API_KEY described in your question with a dummy value.

A common logic for this kind of form is like:

1. Show just the form to choose "city"
   if the request is via GET method.
2. Show calculated/resolved values, ie, temperature and clothes info,
   if and only if the request is via POST method and
   the posted "city" variable is a valid city name.

So your code may be like this:

```
if request.method =='POST':
  city = request.form.get("city")

  request_url = f"{BASE_URL}?lang=fr&appid={API_KEY}&q={city}"
  response = requests.get(request_url)

  if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
       :
       :
    flash_message = "Success! we found your city weather data!!"
    return render_template(
      "weather.html",
      flash_message=flash_message,
      weather=weather,
      temperature=temperature,
      clothing=clothing,
      city=city
    )
  else:
    flash_message= f"Failed! No data found for {city}."
    return render_template(
      "weather.html",
      flash_message=flash_message,
      weather=,
      temperature=,
      clothing=,
      city=city
    )
```

else:
return render_template("weather-form.html")

I hope this may help you!

Comment: The API key should be invalidated/rotated, consider it compromised now. And Stack Overflow has an edit history, even for deleted questions.